# Remove Generic Header Titles from Wordpress Pages and Posts

Tags: css, wordpress, http-headers

I would like to remove a specific  header from my blog posts on my wordpress site. The first H1 header on every post is the generic "Blog" header from the Blog page and not the  Header from the actual title of my post.

I have tried to hide the title using CSS and plugins, but all that does is remove the header from view, not the actual code that crawlers see.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more information; are you using a commercial theme, are you using a child theme, a custom theme - can we see the header file, can we see the `header.php`, `single.php`, `template-parts/content.php` or their equivalents?

Comment: @TonyDjukic We will require more info to help you with this one. Are you trying to hide an element or div or specific words or logo. Please let us know.

Comment: Sorry, I am using standard commercial theme and Elementor. Here is how the HTML looks.  <header class="page-header">
<div class="container clr page-header-inner">
<h1 class="page-header-title clr __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" itemprop="headline">Blog</h1>

Comment: I am not trying to hide anything, necessarily, as I can already hide it from view with CSS. I am mainly trying to have the <h1> of "Blog" not be read by the SEO crawlers. Every blog post I have is being read by the crawlers as Blog and then whatever the title of the post second.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: You're going to have to make a child theme and replace the segment that outputs the title, either by replacing the template for that page, or by deactivating the action that outputs that segments (if is through an action)  or you are going to have to edit the commercial theme.  Every theme is different so I can't even begin to suggest how you can do this.